# Long shutdown times in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, performance

I'm experiencing long shutdown times in Windows 7 Professional on newly built machines.  After joining to a domain, they take over ten minutes to shut down.  There is almost no software installed besides VNC and Office 2010.  I ran a shutdown trace with Windows Performance Recorder and generated a graph of what's running during these long shutdowns.  Most of the shutdown processes occur within the first minute or so and then `wininit.exe` (blue) and `System` (orange).

[image: Shutdown analysis]

So how do I go about reducing shutdown times in this scenario?

Comment: disconnect one from the network then shut it down.  does it still take a long time?

Comment: I don't have another performance report, but yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look at the summary of the disk graph. I can see you have a lot of disk IO.

Maybe you clear the pagefile at shutdown.

To check it, open regedit, go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management`, locate the value `ClearPageFileAtShutdown` and make sure the value is set to `0`.

This can cause such a slowdowns.

Comment: This was it.  It must be defined in group policy or something.  Thanks!

Comment: [Brilliant answer] Shutdown: Clear virtual memory pagefile.  See more here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc740219(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 1):

By default on shutdown, Windows waits 12 seconds per each active application to close before forcing it. You can try tweaking the wait time to see if you speed up the shutdown process. You need to open regedit and go to this location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
```

Then right click on `WaitToKillServiceTimeout` and click on Modify, then add the desired value in milliseconds. Any value between 1-20 seconds (1000-20000) works without problems.